# Flex nested ArrayCollections sorting

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an ArrayCollection nested in another one. I need to sort the child collection by a field.
I tried the following code. It works fine for the parent collection, but does nothing for the child one.

```
    // The Data 

public class Data
{
  public var value:String;
  public var otherValue:String;
  public var childrenData:ArrayCollection; // An array collection containing Data objects.
} 

// The sorting function 

private function sortData():void
{
  var records:ArrayCollection() = bla bla (init the collection with some Data objects).

  records.sort = new Sort();
  records.sort.fields = [
    new SortField('value', true, false)
  ];

  for each (var data:Data in records){
    sortChildren(data);
  }
  records.refresh();   
}

private function sortChildren(data:Data):void
{
  if (data.childrenData != null) {
    var srt:Sort = new Sort();
    srt.fields = [
      new SortField('otherValue', true, false)
    ];
    data.childrenData.sort = srt;
    data.childrenData.refresh();
  }  
}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, so some help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why it happens. However, it looks like `sort` is inherited to its child collections...

Would it be possible to sort the elmenents in `childData` by `value` **and** by `otherValue`? In that case you can use a `IHierarchicalCollectionView` to sort all elements. Take a look at the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" initialize="init()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.collections.HierarchicalCollectionView;
            import mx.collections.HierarchicalData;
            import mx.collections.IHierarchicalCollectionView;
            import mx.collections.Sort;
            import mx.collections.SortField;

            private var records:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                new Data("S", null, new ArrayCollection([
                    new Data(null, "R", null),
                    new Data(null, "B", null),
                    new Data(null, "L", null)
                ])),
                new Data("A", null, new ArrayCollection([
                    new Data(null, "P", null),
                    new Data(null, "O", null)
                ])),
                new Data("X", null, new ArrayCollection([
                    new Data(null, "C", null),
                    new Data(null, "F", null),
                    new Data(null, "E", null)
                ]))
                ]);

            [Bindable]
            private var hierarchicalView:IHierarchicalCollectionView;

            private function init():void
            {
                var hierarchicalRecords:HierarchicalData = new HierarchicalData(records);

                // you don't need this if your field is named 'children' which is the default...
                hierarchicalRecords.childrenField = "childrenData";

                hierarchicalView = new HierarchicalCollectionView(hierarchicalRecords);
                sortData(hierarchicalView);
            }

            private function sortData(view:IHierarchicalCollectionView):void
            {
                var x:ArrayCollection;
                view.sort = new Sort();
                view.sort.fields = [new SortField('value', true, false), new SortField('otherValue', true, false)];
                view.refresh();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
    </s:layout>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid designViewDataType="tree" height="80%" dataProvider="{hierarchicalView}"
                         creationComplete="event.currentTarget.expandAll()">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="value"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="otherValue"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</s:Application>
```

Another option would be to write a `compareFunction` that compares your objects accordingly.